# C++0x lambda for makecontext argument #2

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm having trouble passing a C++0x lambda function as the second argument to `makecontext` (from ucontext.h). The signature of `makecontext` is:

```
void makecontext(ucontext_t*, void (*)(), int, ...);
```

Previously, I was able to apply a C-style `(void (*)(void))` cast, to the global scope functions I used. A `reinterpret_cast` would do the trick in C++. However, with a C++0x lambda function, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>’ to type ‘void (*)()’
```

I'm using G++ 4.6. The following code is sufficient to produce the compile error:

```
#include <ucontext.h>

void f1(int i) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ucontext_t c;
  makecontext(&c, (void (*)(void))f1, 1, 123); // ok
  makecontext(&c, reinterpret_cast<void (*)(void)>(f1), 1, 123); // ok

  auto f2 = [](int i){};
  makecontext(&c, (void (*)(void))f2, 1, 123); // error
  makecontext(&c, reinterpret_cast<void (*) (void)>(f2), 1, 123); // error
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am shocked that converting from `void(*)(int)` to `void(*)(void)` is allowable.

Comment: @user: What you're trying to do is fundamentally wrong. `void(*)()` simply isn't the same as `void (*)(int)`. Types are there for a reason, don't just try to cast it away. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GMan:  I think this is in fact the intended use of the POSIX `makecontext` function.  [The documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html) is vague and I am unfamiliar with this function so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @GMan: I'm trying to use `makecontext`.

Comment: @James: Ah, silly POSIX breaking rules. I think you're right.

Comment: @user: Why have you declared `f2` to take an `int` parameter? `makecontext` expects a function with an empty parameter list. If you declare `f2` properly, it seems to me that your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm curious about the fact that since `makecontext` is using C, it's really expecting a `void(*)(...)`, not a `void(*)(void)` (or is that a special case for e.g. function pointers?). I'm not familiar enough with the guarantees of POSIX to know if the distinction is important. (e.g. is there a POSIX platform where passing an `int` to `void(int)` is different from passing an `int` to `void(...)`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[](int i){}` is a captureless lambda that has a single `int` parameter and returns nothing; it is thus implicitly  convertible to `void(*)(int)`:  a pointer to a function that takes a single `int` and returns nothing.

Assuming the `makecontext` function is capable of handling functions with different types (it appears from its documentation that it is, though the documentation is a bit vague), then you'll need to use two casts to use it with a lambda:  one to cast the lambda to a function pointer, and one to cast the lambda to the `void(*)()` type:

```
auto f2 = [](int i) { };
makecontext(&c, (void (*)(void))(void (*)(int))f2, 1, 123);
```

This is all rather unsafe (casting between function pointer types isn't exactly the safest thing to be doing), so it would be best to wrap this sort of functionality into a utility library.  You can wrap the `makecontext` function with a function template so that you can be sure that all of your uses of the function are type safe, and all of the unsafe code is encapsulated in one place.

Comment: Very helpful James, thanks. I like your answer as it needs no other libraries or headers.

Comment: double cast ? what does it mean ??

Comment: Sadly, I *will* also be dealing with lambda functions which are closures/do capture. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: @user:  You shouldn't need to capture anything; since you can pass an arbitrary number of arguments via `makecontext`, you can just pass the "captured" variables as arguments (either by value or by pointer), no?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only given the function object, as a `typename F`. I will know the arity though (1 in my example) and had the idea of using a wrapper template function with the first argument the function object. It may not work anyway, but `auto f3 = [=](int i){...}; auto f4 = wrap1<decltype(f3)>;` isn't happening.

Comment: `makecontext` takes a function pointer of type `void(*)()` which in C is different from `void(*)(void)`: the formal parameter list is unspecified, not empty. I think the safest way to do this in C++ is with an `extern "C" typedef`. And, lambdas specifically do not implicitly convert to C calling conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have already declared `f2` as in your example, and want to use it now with `makecontext`. Rather  than trying to cast it, use `std::bind` (found in the <functional> header) to produce an object which is callable like a `void(*)(void)`:

```
auto f3 = std::bind(f2, 0);
makecontext(&c, f3, 1, 123);
```

The object `f3` is a function object which is callable without any arguments. The end result is that `f2` end up being called with 0 as its argument. If you would rather a different value be passed to `f2`, you can specify it as the second argument to `bind`.

### Edit

As several commenters have pointed out, this isn't applicable in your case, as `makecontext` requires an actual function pointer. So, for reference sake, I thought I would point out one caveat that you might run into (in case you don't already know this): using a lambda as a function pointer only works if you don't utilize closures. As soon as you close over variables, the lambda can no longer degenerate to a function pointer, as it can without a closure.

Comment: Indeed it is a function object...which isn't a function pointer. So it can't be used as the second argument.

Comment: The functor returned by `bind` is indeed callable as if it were a `void(*)(void)`, but that doesn't mean it _is_ a `void(*)(void)`.

Comment: @Ken: I like the idea. By the way, what's the name of the header containing `std::bind`?

Comment: Yes, you guys are all correct. Since this was a C++0x question I jumped all over the functor hype. I failed to consider that a plain function pointer was needed. @user643722: I had a run-in with HTML tags inside backticks. It's there now

Comment: @Ken: Indeed as the others suggest, it doesn't seem to work. Shame, I really do like your use of `std::bind`. I assume the code "should" then change to `auto f3 = std::bind(f2,123); makecontext(&c, (void (*)(void))f3, 0);`

Comment: @user643722: I wish that were possible. It would definitely be nice sometimes be nice to cast general function objects to their function pointer equivalents.

Comment: @Ken: Would your Edit comments have implications to James' answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper function to wrap it.
It works for every lambda.
The idea behind it is that since you can not pass functor as function pointer, you can pass a wrapper function that calls the lambda function. Another trick part is that I need to pass pointer instead of the whole object, it is because makecontext can only accept int arguments.

```
template<typename Kernel, typename ...Args>
void wrapper(Kernel *ker, Args*... args)
{
    (*ker)(*args...);
}
template<typename Ker, typename ...Args>
void makectx(Ker ker, Args... args)
{
    makecontext(&ctx, (void (*)(void))wrapper<Ker, Args...>, sizeof...(Args) + 1, &ker, &args...);
}
```