# Template function causes a compiler error when used with local lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809890/c0x-lambda-for-makecontext-argument-2) concluded that a distasteful "double cast" might be necessary to use the POSIX `makecontext` with a C++ lambda function (i.e. function object). Moving on, I'm now faced with a compilation error relating to the following minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ucontext.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> void foo()   {
  ucontext_t c;
  auto f = [=](int i){ cout << i << endl; };
  makecontext(&c, (void (*) (void)) (void (*)(int)) f, 1, 12345);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  foo<int>();
  return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘foo() [with T = int]::<lambda(int)>’ to type ‘void (*)(int)’
```

However, if I remove the unused (in this example) template argument from the `foo` function, so it becomes `void foo();`, and change the call to `foo()` the error disappears. Could someone tell me why? I'm using G++ 4.6.

Edit:

From the comments below, it seems the `[=]` in the code above causes the lambda to be a "capturing" lambda, regardless of the fact that it doesn't actually capture anything. The `[=]` is not necessary in my code, alas replacing with `[]` in GCC 4.6 does not remove the error. I am installing GCC 4.6.1 now...

Comment: This compiles fine in GCC 4.6.1.

Comment: Beware though, it's not supposed to. As you see in the answers, capturing lambdas aren't convertible to function pointers. This is probably an optimization because you aren't capturing anything, but if you did add `c` to the lambda body, it'd fail.

Comment: Hmm, it does compile with 4.6.1, but if I make it a capturing lambda, that also compiles :(

Comment: You have to actually *use* the capture by referring to it in the lambda body. Otherwise it might get optimized away.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I added a new `int`, `j`, to give `cout << i << " " << j << endl;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `[=]` to induce your lambda, you will not get a function pointer (or an object that is convertible to one). You will get a function *object*. And no amount of casting is going to allow you to pass that to `makecontext`. Not in any way that actually works.

According to N3291, the most recent working draft of C++0x:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same eﬀect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

This is the *only* place where the specification allows conversion to a function pointer. Therefore, if recent versions of GCC do allow conversion to function pointers for [=], that not in accord with the specification.

Comment: Actually, `[=]` and `[&]` are suppose to only capture what's used. Since nothing from the outer scope is used, it should act is if it were `[]`.

Comment: @Nicol: The function objects produced by captureless lambdas can be converted to function pointers. Follow the link to my previous question.

Comment: @GMan: See my edit. It most ceratinly should _not_ act as if it were []. [=] has a default capture, which according to the grammar counts as a capture.

Comment: @user643722: I know that captureless lambdas can be converted to function pointers. But [=] is not a captureless lambda, which was the point of my answer.

Comment: @Nicol: Hm, very interesting. I'm positive they intend for any lambda that doesn't capture anything to be convertible to a function pointer, but you're right: according to the grammar, it can't. I tried looking for a report to see if anyone noticed this, but didn't find anything. As your answer says, if it really is the case no captures are needed we can just change it to `[]`, but for uniformity they should have worded that differently. +1 then. I'll have to see why gcc allows it, I'll get back to you if I find it.

Comment: @Nicol: Thanks for that; very interesting. I'm happy to change to [] here, but alas it doesn't remove the error. This is presumably the bug that Kerrek doesn't see in GCC 4.6.1, which I'm now installing...

Answer (score 3):

Only captureless lambdas are convertible to function pointers; while `f` technically does not capture anything, it does have a default capture mode of capturing by value (for no apparent reason).

Change `[=]` to `[]` in the declaration of `f` and it should work as expected.

**EDIT:** The fact that this compiles with more recent versions of GCC (as noted by Kerrek) gives a strong indication that this is merely a compiler bug in the version you're using.

Comment: I tried changing it to [] anyway, but it made no difference to the error. Interesting to hear that about GCC 4.6.1.

Comment: I'm supposing that this lambda does in fact not capture anything, because `[=]` is just syntactic sugar to be resolved at compile time, which resolved to `[]` in this case. (See GMan's comment below.)